# How to convert Javascript date to LocalDate for a Spring @RequestParam?

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a `@RestController` with a method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/getInvoices")
public List<InvoiceDto> getInvoices(@RequestParam(name="date") @DateTimeFormat LocalDate date) {
 // do stuff and return a list of InvoiceDtos
}
```

But when the JavaScript client sends a request such as http://localhost:8080/getInvoices?date=Thu+Nov+30+2017+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0600+(Central+Standard+Time)

the server reports:

> 2017-12-20 16:20:03.123  WARN 10324 --- [nio-9003-exec-7]
>   .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request
>   element:
>   org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
>   Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
>   'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
>   convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
>   [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
>   @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
>   java.time.LocalDate] for value 'Thu Nov 30 2017 23:20:02 GMT-0600
>   (Central Standard Time)'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
>   [Thu Nov 30 2017 23:20:02 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)]

How can I convert this String representation of the date (ignoring the time component) to a LocalDate?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `pattern` attribute:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z")
```